# Solr 9 UI not loading but working with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solr, solrcloud, solr9

Recently updated the solr version from 8.4.1 to 9.0.0 on EC2 Linux AMI 2.

I'm getting the result when i'm using the cli using the localhost domain-> curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/select?q=(fieldname%3A\fieldvalue%20)&start=0".

But when I try to use the EC2's elastic IP it says the connection refused. It was working well with the previous version. I configured it locally before trying in EC2, it worked fine in local but not on EC2.Not sure what's missing.

[Scrrenshot of browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNrKF.png)

Solr Status

[Solr status screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEQeg.png)

Comment: you could try a few things - if somewhere solr is running on 127.0.0.1, replace that with 0.0.0.0 & also check if some firewall is blocking the connections in the ec2. And check security groups

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IArc13 Thanks - I uncommented and changed the SOLR_JETTY_HOST in solr.in.sh ( linux ) from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 (not recommended in production or pre-prod ). However EC2 security group is mapped only to my IP for port 8983 so it works.

Answer (score 1):

Uncommented and changed the SOLR_JETTY_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in solr.in.sh file. Deleted everything and reindexed the core after updating the jetty host.